# How to trigger a static analyzer warning on a specific code path?

Tags: static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

I'm looking for a way to trigger a static analyzer warning on specific code path that would normally not happen or indicate an unhandled error condition.

For example, I would like do write something like this:

```
int err = some_internal_call(arg1, arg2);
if (err == errInternalError) {
    analyzer_assert(); 
}
```

Then when I run the analyzer, and it analyze all the different code path, it would warn me that the analyzer_assert() has been called.

Specifically looking into the clang analyzer, but I'm also curious if other analyzer have this feature.

It looks like I could add this feature to clang by write a custom checker, but I'd rather not have to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Many analyzers have diagnostics, warning that conditions are always false or true. To find such situations you can use many different tools. But apparently you need another thing. You want to find always true/false conditions because of which a function with a certain name is always/never called, don't you?

If yes, most likely, there is no a ready-made solution. You need to either implement such functional yourself using Clang or you can reach out to someone who can do such a custom service for you. For example, our team implements similar customer-specific rules in a PVS-Studio analyzer. Such diagnostics are included in a separate group and are disabled by default. However, you can always enable and start using such diagnostics.